# how to use ignore_index in torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

Given a sequence: `a b c [SEP] d e f`,
the corresponding labels is : `-1 -1 -1 0 1 0 0`.

I want to compute the loss `loss_func(logits,labels,ignore_index=-1)` to ignore the tokens before `[SEP]`.
And I got a `RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1603729096996`.

So I have to change labels to "class indice mode" like `4`, but how to ignore the previous tokens when calculating loss.